# Regular expression on website

Tags: php, yii2, expression, rules

I have this regular expression in rules in yii2:

```
 [['Url'],  'match', 'pattern' => '/^(http(s?):\/\/)?(www\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\s\.\/\?\%\#\&\=]*)?$/'],
```

What can i do to improve this url that this 'www.' it may be but is not necessarily. By second side could not enter 'google.pl' soi if he used http:// he can used www., but it not necessary, but he cant write google.pl without www.

Comment: If you wrote the regex yourself I wouldn't see where the problem is. But `+` means 1 or more times and you probably want `*` 0 or more times.

Comment: by second side could not enter 'google.pl' soi if he used http:// he can used www. but it not necessary, but he cant write google.pl without www.

Comment: Why not using yiI2 url validator ?? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make "www." optional at the moment it's required and may even be present multiple times due to the usage of `+`. Use `?` to denote optional parts.

```
[['Url'],  'match', 'pattern' => '/^(http(s?):\/\/)?(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\s\.\/\?\%\#\&\=]*)?$/'],
```

Comment: or use * if you want to keep current behaviour but allow 0 occurences